# Table Data with sort, search query, pagination pass to different component in Angular

Tags: mysql, django, angular

I will try to explain as simple as possible.

There is a table which in start gets first 30 rows of n rows and has sorting, search using mat-table. So even if it is sorted only the first 30 rows will be sent and when the user goes to next page it gets the next 30 rows from backend each time making a new request.

Now each row has a button that will take it to another component which will get some detailed data about the specific row.

This component has a previous and next feature that will get the detailed view of the next or previous row data in the same order that is displayed in the table(sorted, search Result, page number).


Currently the table rows are made again in backend(Django) with all the sort, search and other parameters then find the current row and send the next and previous row (will take minimum 5 hits on DB).
Hence it very slow.

In Frontend I can only pass the data of only that page, which will have problem in next or previous page.

How to properly tackle this...

Answer (score 0):

Normal search UIs don't focus on 30 rows at a time.  Instead, they first search the entire dataset, then 'paginate' the results.  (Or is that what you intended to say?)

There are details that can let the processing work fast, or there may be details that prevent speed.  Please go into details about the table structure and the possible search criteria.